# Adding event to a WatchKit item of a table

Tags: button, watchkit

I have created a table in which the items contains some groups and some labels. I would like that when the user tap on the item, I receive an action. How can I do it? Is it possible to add an invisible button covering all the area of an item of the table?

[image: Here is what ii is inside the table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Button can contain groups (you have to choose this option in the editor) so the problem is solved! I don't understand why this answer is rated negatively. It works!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to connect the table row to another Interface Controller by control dragging from the row, and selecting `push` or `modal`.

[image]

Give the Storyboard Segue an identifier (string).

[image]

Then, to pass data to the Interface Controller, override `contextForSegueWithIdentifier:inTable:rowIndex`:

Swift:

```
override func contextForSegueWithIdentifier(segueIdentifier: String, inTable table: WKInterfaceTable, rowIndex: Int) -> AnyObject? {
    if segueIdentifier == "identifier" {
        return "banana"
    }
    return nil
}
```

Objective-C:

```
- (nullable id)contextForSegueWithIdentifier:(nonnull NSString *)segueIdentifier inTable:(nonnull WKInterfaceTable *)table rowIndex:(NSInteger)rowIndex {
    if ([segueIdentifier isEqualToString:@"identifier"]) {
        return @"banana";
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I have solved in a better way. I forgotten to answer my own question. Now I did it.